# POD X3 Live with M-Audio Oxygen V4

Tags: midi, sound, midi-controller-keyboard

1. I have POD X3 Live
2. I would like to buy and use M-Audio Oxygen 49 V4 for home recording
3. My computer's operating system is Windows 8.1 x64
4. I will use Cubase, Ableton or Protools for music production.

So, am i able to use POD X3 live as a sound card with low(or zero) latency with its USB Port ?

Or should i buy an external sound card ?

**---UPDATE---**

I bought my Oxygen 49 v4. And its working quite well with my POD X3 Live sound card. Yeah a little bit delay happens but i don't even feel it, like <10ms.

Thank you all for your participation.

Comment: I believe you can use the POD as an [ASIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output) soundcard with low latency in this setting (Windows). That's how I used a POD in the past, but not with those programs.

Comment: Which recording program did you use ?

Comment: At that point I used a simple program from Line6. I have used other ASIO devices with Sonar X1 LE and experienced similar low latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the POD HD 500, and despite it having an excellent set of output circuits I still need to use a soundcard in order to reduce latency when recording.

I would assume that the X3 live latency is the same or worse than the HD500, so I'd advise buying a good external soundcard.

I went for one of the M-Audio ones. Reasonable price point and loads of in/outs

**Update** - from your comments I now see what you want to do with this one. The above refers only to audio, but if you want to use any of the midi functionality then it all needs to go across the USB port, as that keyboard has no midi connector. Applications that understand DirectLink can be controlled by the keyboard.

Comment: Okay then, Is 24-bit/48 kHz is enough for getting a low latency ? I am also  planning to buy M-Audio Oxygen 49 V4 but it only has USB output port. No midi output ports (here's the image : http://8e5aac4bc793d119543e-a784f0287de17aca81e7ecc053e60785.r69.cf2.rackcdn.com/926/images/Oxygen49_back_media.jpg). So i don't know how to connect oxygen 49 through external soundcard. Do i need to buy a midi keyboard has midi output, connect it through external soundcard midi input, and then to computer ? Like This : Keyboard Midi Output->Sound Card Midi Input->Usb Output->Computer USB input

Comment: Or is it like that : 1. I plugged in my external card through computer usb port and selected it as the default soundcard drive. 2. I connected midi keyboard to my computer through another usb port. Sorry for being so beginner.

Comment: The 24bit/48kHz isn't exactly related to latency. Higher bitrates have more of an impact on editing quality.

Comment: what exactly affects latency ? especially when buying sound card ?

Comment: @DemonDrake -- "what features of a sound card affect latency" is probably a good, separate, question.

Comment: @DrMayhem: I used the POD XT as an ASIO device, and got low latency. Isn't this an option?

Comment: I guess it comes down to what latency you consider low enough - the PODs latency is too annoying for many folks.I did a quick check on the POD X3 and it is around the same as the XT. I wouldn't like it.